# Stop multiples threads if error ocurred and keep running the main thread ? Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Is there a way to stop all threads in the list if an error occurs in any of them without stopping the main thread ?

```
from threading import Thread

def build_packages(pkg_id):
    try:
        # do something
    except Exception:
        # stop all threads except main thread

threads = []

for pkg_id in pkgs:
    t = Thread(target=build_packages, args=[pkg_id])

    threads.append(t)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```